# First item in a SortedDictionary?

Tags: vb.net, sorteddictionary

There are many, *many* threads on ways to get the "first" item from a `Dictionary`, and various answers as to why such a thing is not really a good idea because there's no internal ordering. But mine's a `SortedDictionary`, so those arguments don't apply. Yet I cannot find a way to get the Nth item from a `SortedDictionary` any easier than a `Dictionary`.

Here is my SD:

```
FRs As SortedDictionary(Of DateTime, ScheduleItem)
```

I see a few hints that I should be able to do:

```
If FRs.Count = 1 Then
    FirstFR = FRs.Keys(0)
```

But that is not valid in my code - it says it has no defaults and cannot be indexed. `.First` and other options appear to all be in LINQ, which I cannot target. So is there any simple way to access it in this fashion?

Note: any solution offered **must not use LINQ**, which does not exist on many non-Wintel platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a `SortedDictionary` is indeed ordered by the key. But that does not mean that you can access it via index. So if you can't use LINQ:

```
Dim firstFR As KeyValuePair(Of DateTime, ScheduleItem)
For Each kv In FRs
    firstFR = kv
    Exit For
Next
```

Otherwise you could simply use `First`/ `FirstOrDefault`.

Sidenote: since a `KeyValuePair(Of Tkey, TValue)` is a structure, therefore a value type, it is never `null`/`Nothing`. You could check for an empty dictionary in this ugly way:

```
If firstFR.Equals(New KeyValuePair(Of DateTime, ScheduleItem))
    Console.WriteLine("Empty dictionary")
End If
```

So it's much more readable to use `If FRs.Count = 0 Then ...`.

---

<strike>**Update**: if you just want the key or value at a given index you can use:</strike>

```
Dim firstSchedule As Date = FRs.Keys(0)
```

or the first `Date` in it:

```
Dim firstDate As ScheduleItem = FRs.Values(0)
```

On this way you could actually get both via index even without LINQ:

```
Dim firstFR = new KeyValuePair(Of DateTime, ScheduleItem)(FRs.Keys(0), FRs.Values(0))
```

Disclaimer: according to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933428/why-can-i-access-an-item-in-keycollectio-valuecollection-by-index-even-if-it-doe?noredirect=1#comment61426737_36933428) this works only if you have imported `System.Linq`, then `Enumerable.ElementAt` is used implicitly which enumerates a sequence to find an item via index if the type doesn't implement `IList(Of T)`. So don't use it in this case.

Comment: Ok thanks Tim. Again another "what were they thinking" moment. Actually, there's really no reason they couldn't do this with a default is there?

Comment: It does not work in my code, I get an error about there being no default or index. To be exact: 'Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Keys As SortedDictionary(Of Date, ScheduleItem).KeyCollection' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed

Comment: ...which is proving rather annoying when trying to reverse iterate over the collection and remove duplicates.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: strange, you're right. But it compiles and works for me. Interesting

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: i've created a question about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933428/why-can-i-access-an-item-in-keycollectio-valuecollection-by-index-even-if-it-doe?noredirect=1#comment61426737_36933428

Answer (score 2):

Linq is mostly just a series of extension methods, so you can write own:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module EnumerableExtensions

    <Extension()> 
    Public Function FirstValue(Of TKey, TValue)(source As SortedDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)) As TValue
        For Each kvp In source
            Return kvp.Value
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Module

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim a As SortedDictionary(Of string, string) = new SortedDictionary(Of string, string)
        a.Add("foo", "1 - foo")
        a.Add("bar", "2 - bar")
        Console.WriteLine(a.FirstValue())
    End Sub
End Module
```

Here's the example running in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/81GLhP).

Answer (score 0):

just implemented <Extension()> example; added also an extension to access the last entry;
here my working code:

```
''' <summary>
''' return the first object of a sortedDictionary
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="TKey">Key tpye</typeparam>
''' <typeparam name="TValue">value type</typeparam>
''' <param name="source">dictionary</param>
''' <returns></returns>

<Extension()>
Public Function FirstValue(Of TKey, TValue)(source As SortedDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)) As TValue
    For Each kvp As TValue In source.Values
        Return kvp
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
''' <summary>
''' return the last object of a sortedDictionary
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="TKey">Key type</typeparam>
''' <typeparam name="TValue"> value type</typeparam>
''' <param name="source"> dictionary</param>
''' <returns>the last object or nothing for an empty dictionary</returns>
<Extension()>
Public Function lastValue(Of TKey, TValue)(source As SortedDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)) As TValue
    Dim lv As TValue = Nothing
    For Each kvp As TValue In source.Values
        lv = kvp
    Next
    Return lv
End Function
```